# Show that the complex series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} z^n$ converges nowhere on the unit circle.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

> Show that the complex series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} z^n$ converges
>   nowhere on the unit circle.

Just looking for a simple solution to this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the necessary condition for convergence: $a_n := z^n$ does not converge to $0$, since $|a_n| = 1$ for every $n$.

Comment: Can you explain why $|a_n|=1$ means $a_n$ does not converge to 0?  I've only just started complex analysis.

Comment: If $a_n \to 0$, then also $|a_n| \to 0$.